# Python random.choices() query

Tags: python

```
import random

a_list = [1,2]
dist = [0.9,0.1]
random_number = random.choices(a_list,dist)
print(random_number)
```

Is it possible to get the output of this as an int? I am building a game of cricket where I need the random choice to be added the the players current score but cannot as Py cannot cannot perform additions on list and get `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'`.

Comment: If you want to use `choices` , then just set `k=1` and read the element of the list using `random_number[0]`. However, I agree why not use `random.choice`

Comment: @AnuragReddy I made a comment to that effect and then looked it up, and apparently `random.choice()` doesn't support adding weights to outcomes like `random.choices()` does. That's probably the reason here.

Comment: @AnuragReddy: `random.choice` does not accept `weights`.

Answer (score 2):

When called without a `k` argument, `random.choices()` will return a list containing one element. You can then withdraw that one element like you'd access any other list element.

```
random_number = random.choice(a_list, dist)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked.. cant believe I couldn't figure it out